# Laravel doesn't delete directory

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1

I have a problem deleting a directory.

I'm creating a temporary directory where I unzip a file and I want to delete it when I'm done with it.

My code looks pretty much like this:

```
$tempPath = storage_path('temp/'.$filemd5.'/');
Storage::makeDirectory($tempPath);
$success = Storage::deleteDirectory($tempPath);
return $success;
```

It doesn't return anything and the directory doesn't get deleted.

Comment: One thing to be noted here. The Storage facade works within the ROOT/storage directory or whatever you would have set in the config/filesystem.php file. To delete files outside of your app's "storage" scope you should use File facade instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe you don't have enough permissions on your `storage/app` directory (which I think is the default one). Check that, and if that doesn't work, you can always appeal to the PHP `exec` function (assuming that you're on linux):

`exec('rm -r ' . storage_path() . '/' . $tempPath)`

UPDATE: the problem was that `makeDirectory` has a second `int` parameter that sets the permissions by default to `511` which is `-r-x--x--x` (i.e. read and execute, but not write). The workaround is to set the second parameter to `711` which is `-rwx--x--x` and you'll be able to delete the created directory. It's useful to pass the other two parameter as `true` because it will apply permissions recursively, and force the operation.

As Alex says, you have to use `File` instead of `Storage`. So the final code for creating directory that later you will be able to delete is:

```
File::makeDirectory($tempPath, 0711, true, true);
```

Comment: I'm using `exec` right now, but I'm really curious why that doesn't work. `Storage::copy` doesn't work either, while PHP's `copy` function works.

Comment: The content of the directory is preserved ?

Comment: Maybe the problem is that the `makeDirectory` function has a second argument that is an `int` which holds the permissions over the created directory and its default is `511` which is `-r-x--x--x` so you're not supposed to delete it. Try to run the command with the `711` parameter that is `-rwx--x--x`. `Storage::makeDirectory($tempPath, 711);`

Comment: I recommend you to pass true as the other two argument, as it will apply the permissions recursively and force the operation, so `Storage::makeDirectory($tempPath, 0711, true, true);` [makeDirectory implementation](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/a1dc78820d2dbf207dbdf0f7075f17f7021c4ee8/src/Illuminate/Filesystem/Filesystem.php#L331)

Comment: Ok, I will update the code, thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 8):

I think if you remove the trailing backslash from `$tempPath`, it might work.

`$tempPath = storage_path('temp/'.$filemd5);`

EDIT:

Okay, I tried different methods and looks like the class `File` is the most simple one.

`File::makeDirectory($path)`

and

`File::deleteDirectory($path)`

More about [creating a directory](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/147/creating-a-directory) and [Deleting a directory](http://laravel-recipes.com/recipes/149/recursively-deleting-a-directory)

Answer (score 1):

In my case using laravel 6.*

```
Storage::disk('directory')->deleteDirectory($pathDirectory);
```

Comment: Laravel 8 here, i needed to inform the disk too

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, but with the following exception thrown during directory deletion:

```
RuntimeException(code: 0): SplFileInfo::getType(): Lstat failed for <my file name>
```

The culprit was Vite looking at the contents of my `/storage` directory for purposes of hot-reloading. Somehow that tangled up the deletion logic, resulting in the same file coming up twice for deletion, and failing the second time.

Just in case someone else has the same issue, here is the vite config I used to resolve it:

```
server: {
    watch: {
        ignored: ['**/storage/**'],
    },
},
```